# InfluxDB 2.0 - How to merge and sum 2 separate buckets stream in one with Flux

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

### Context

I work in an application with influxDB and I am facing a use case I don't know how to solve.
I am using influxDB 2 and flux for the queries.

#### Use case

To simplify my use case, I'll take an example with bees.

I want to measure the evolution of the bee population accross time.
I measure 2 populations of bees in 2 separate buckets (bucket A for bee A and bucket B for bee B).
So I want to find a query that merges these 2 buckets to get the current population of bees at any time.
Using 2 buckets is mandatory in my use case. What I want is just a way to "combine" the result when I query.

The results should be sorted based on the timestamps

#### Examples

The query on the `Bee A` and the `Bee B` buckets returns the values in the first 2 lines. The objective is to create the `Total` line.

Example 1:
In case the measurements are always A, B, A, B; the result must be as

| Populations |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bee A | 10 |  | 12 |  | 5 |  | 22 |  |
| Bee B |  | 20 |  | 16 |  | 19 |  | 36 |
| Total | 10 | 30 | 32 | 28 | 21 | 24 | 41 | 58 |

---

Example 2:
In case the measurements are A, B, A, A, A, B; the result must be as

| Populations |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bee A | 10 |  | 12 | 5 | 22 |  |  |  |
| Bee B |  | 20 |  |  |  | 16 | 19 | 36 |
| Total | 10 | 30 | 32 | 25 | 42 | 38 | 41 | 58 |

### Code

I tried using `union` but I couldn't get it to work as it kept 2 separates tables instead of one.

```
bucket1 = from(bucket: "beeA")
  |> range(start: 0)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "population")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "pop")
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"])

bucket2 = from(bucket: "beeB")
  |> range(start: 0)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "population")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "pop")
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"])

union(tables: [bucket1, bucket2])
```

Answer (score 0):

**you Can try by removing**, `|> sort(columns: ["_time"])`.
Also check for `|> range(start: 0)`. You may give different time range and atlast check the selected time range where you have the data.